# Post and Put HTTP Request in Spring Data JPA misbehaving according to default constructor existence

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have a spring data JPA project with validations and trying to make HTTP requests work.

The issue is that with "public Theme() {}" in my entity
POST doesn't work
PUT doesn't work both with error message below(error details after code)

Theme.java (my entity)

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@ToString(exclude="id")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name="theme")
public class Theme {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @Getter @Setter
    @NotBlank(message = "A description must be given")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Getter @Setter
    @NotBlank(message = "A name must be given")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "theme", 
    targetEntity = Event.class)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Event> events;

    public Theme() {}

    public Theme(int id, Date createdAt, String description, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ThemeRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface ThemeRepository extends JpaRepository<Theme, Integer> {}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My POST and PUT JSON Body

```
{
    "description": "Some pretty long text Lorem Ipsum5",
    "name": "Nome da temática5"
}
```

The issue is that with "public Theme() {}"
GET localhost:8080/themes (works fine)
GET localhost:8080/themes/1 (works fine - id=1 just for example)
DELETE localhost:8080/themes/1 (works fine)
POST localhost:8080/themes (doesn't work)
PUT localhost:8080/themes/1 (doesn't work) both with this error message

```
 "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.x.x.entity.Theme] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='A name must be given', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.Robocup.Olimpo.entity.Theme, messageTemplate='A name must be given'}\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='A description must be given', propertyPath=description, rootBeanClass=class com.x.x.entity.Theme, messageTemplate='A description must be given'}\n]\n\tat org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140)\n\tat org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80)\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:203)\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:721)\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:707)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor580.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1345.persist(Unknown Source)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor580.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1345.persist(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor583.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1368.save(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:101)\n\tat org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:176)\n\tat org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.createAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:474)\n\tat org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:266)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor588.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n",
    "message": "Validation failed for classes [com.Robocup.Olimpo.entity.Theme] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='A name must be given', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.Robocup.Olimpo.entity.Theme, messageTemplate='A name must be given'}\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='A description must be given', propertyPath=description, rootBeanClass=class com.Robocup.Olimpo.entity.Theme, messageTemplate='A description must be given'}\n]",
```

without "public Theme() {}"
POST now works with persistence in MySQL 8 and PUT works but with no persistence.
Both gets, and delete stop working. Now with this error

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:
```

Answer (score 1):

There is constraints issue with your json or json not correctly binding or theme object have null value for name and description.

Carefully check the error message they are null due to that you got `constraint violations`

```
@NotBlank(message = "A description must be given")
@NotBlank(message = "A name must be given")
```

nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='A name must be given'
, messageTemplate='A name must be given'}\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='A description must be given',

Comment: I tried to remove the validation entirely, and then I got the mySQL error for trying to insert a null in a not null field, but thr JSON clearly has string in both fields. I don't think is about the validation, the JSON might be misinterpreted somehow. And also without the default constructor this doesn't happen, however this is not a fix because it brokes the get request

Comment: You have to have valid POJO for JSON binding at controller level. Then it will work fine the issue with null.

Answer (score 0):

I added the Jackson dependency to my pom.xml, and it appears everything is working fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

EDIT on the next day, not only that but there was 2 other issues:

1. the "target" folder becomes trashy and it's always good to delete before running spring boot again and retrying.
2. including this line in application.properties "logging.level.org.springframework.data.jpa=DEBUG"
   I could see that the problem is that a NOT NULL field in the DB, demands a default value in the entity, if there is not, it will crash in a 500 error, instead a 400 bad request as it should do.